# Ordering a ManyToMany By Relationship id

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I currently have two models, that have an relationship to each other

**models.py**

```
class Key(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Grouping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    keys = models.ManyToManyField(Key)
```

and a admin page configuration, that shows the gorupings in the key page:

**admin.py**

```
class GroupingInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Grouping.keys.through
    extra = 1

class GroupingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields to configure 
    fieldsets = [
        (None,                  {'fields':['name']}),
    ]

class KeyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields to configure and their options
    fieldsets = [ 
        ('Key-Name',            {'fields':['name']}),
    ]

    inlines = [GroupingInline]

admin.site.register(Key, KeyAdmin)
admin.site.register(Grouping, GroupingAdmin)
```

In Admin-Page, i can directly add the relationship for key 2 grouping from the key admin page. That way, i also can decide the order of the groupings for the key.
Now, is there any possibility to replicate this ordering in a template? Using

```
{% for grouping in key.grouping_set.all %}
```

seems to order the groupings by their id.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're "deciding the order of the groupings" in the admin page, can you explain?

Comment: Sure, thanks to the configuration in admin.py, i have the groupings at the bottom of the admin page for an key-entry (GroupingInline). That way, i can add a grouping directly. The ordering is the sequence, in which the groupings are shown here. [Example of Admin Page](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aok8oU4pVzYZiKx1zKRteuTKeOB78A)